# Load composer dependencies of private git repository

Tags: composer-php

I've been a bit confused how Composer loads dependencies of a private repository project. I have found this link but I am not sure if [this comment](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) is referring to *nested* repositories or simply any dependency of a repository. To clarify my situation:

1. I have a private git repository that I am attempting to add as a dependency for a project.
2. The private git repository is also a composer project, which contains a composer.json which requires publicly available packages.

I have the following code in my composer.json for the project.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "{vendor}/{package-name}",
            "version": "{arbitrary-version}",
            "type": "package",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@github.com:{github-username}/{github-repository}.git",
                "type": "git",
            }
        }
    }
]
"require": {
    "{vendor}/{package-name}": "^0.0.1"
}
```

So if I were to do `composer update` on the project after these changes it will successfully download my package from the private repository, but it does not trigger a check/update on the composer.json of the private repository - so no vendor folder is created and critical dependencies are not installed. The private repository composer.json is below:

```
{
    "name": "{vendor}/{package-name}",
    "description": "{removed}",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "^5.6",
        "chumper/zipper": "1.0.x",
        "symfony/debug": "^4.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
    },
}
```

So my question is, is what I want to do achievable with a private repository via composer and if so does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`package`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) type is for non-composer dependencies. If you use this type, Composer will not even look for `composer.json` file inside of defined package source, you need to include all required information about package inside of the package declaration in your project `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "{vendor}/{package-name}",
            "description": "{removed}",
            "type": "library",
            "require": {
                "illuminate/database": "^5.6",
                "chumper/zipper": "1.0.x",
                "symfony/debug": "^4.0",
                "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
            },
            "version": "{arbitrary-version}",
            "source": {
                "url": "git@github.com:{github-username}/{github-repository}.git",
                "type": "git",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But in your case (you have a package with proper `composer.json`) you should use `vcs` type:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:{github-username}/{github-repository}.git"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, knew I was probably doing something simple wrong. I know it's beyond the scope of my original issue but unfortunately now at the very end of the `composer update` process after composer install's all the packages from my repo but when it goes to install/clone the actual repository it spits out:

    "{package}/{name}": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git",
      "no-api": true
    }
  ]

I am also using the `--prefer-source` flag so not sure why it's still trying to use dist?

Comment: A little bit more info if it helps:

Now trying to download from dist- Installing {package}/{repo} (dev-master acb616e) Downloading: Failed[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]The "https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo}/zipball/acb616ee90ef5715641c7b91373d4c0613d9749b" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Comment: @XanT Try to change `vcs` to `git` in type declaration.

Comment: no luck but you helped me solve my main issue so I've marked it as accepted. Changing it from `vcs` to `git` did change it from a Transport Exception to a Runtime Exception now but the same message persists.I'll have to debug more, thanks for your help.

Comment: @XanT You can try delete `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file. And clear composer cache: `composer clearcache`. I'm not sure why it does not work with `git` as a type, maybe it is related with cache.

Comment: @roboo6 - I was able to resolve it, I believe it was a problem with Composer not correctly picking up my ssh key for the private repository. Thanks for all your help!